# Why is Roller Coaster Tycoon displaying a black screen on startup with Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: technical-issues, rollercoaster-tycoon

I know there is a similar question to this one, but the person asking that question was running the game on a virtual machine on a Mac. I'm currently trying to run it on an HP Pavilion dv7 quad core with a Radeon 6770M graphics card and a Core i7 processor. I've tried different compatibility settings, making it administrative on opening, and all the other recommended stuff for getting this program to work; nothing has worked. I can hear the music, but I can't see any of the opening animations. And when I ALT-TAB out and go back in, the title screen is static and in black and white. Can anyone help?

Comment: And you have experimented with all the colour/resolution settings on the Compatibility tab?

Comment: The 256 color and 640x480resolution checkboxes? Yes, I've tried those too, and it won't work.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on win7 without using a virtual machine running windows xp, and even then sometimes it would work and sometimes It just wouldn't.

Comment: The main reason is that it was programmed in assembly language (!) and as such, heavily relies upon the Windows 9x x86 architecture.

Comment: Odd, this game works just fine for me on the same computer with the default configuration. Have you changed anything pertaining to the graphics drivers?